# React.js: Spinner animation stops when rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, spinner, lifecycle

I made a simple spinner which will be displayed during the process. The animation should be running until the tables are rendered, but my spinner animation is working when fetching data, but then it just stuck for a few second before rendering the tables. I am not sure if it is because the data is too much and the rendering process is slow

I am using react hook...

```
 useEffect(async () => {
    if (spinner === null) {
      const tor = await axios.get("http://localhost:8080/api/tor");
      const uk = await axios.get("http://localhost:8080/api/uk");
      const ny = await axios.get("http://localhost:8080/api/ny");
      setInfo({
        tor: tor.data,
        uk: uk.data,
        ny: ny.data,
      });

      setSpinner(false);
    }
  }, []);
  let tables = null;

  if (info.tor != null) {
    console.log(info);
    tables = (
      <Container>
        <Element name="tor">
          <br />
          <h1 className="display-4">Toronto</h1>
          <Table info={info.tor} />
        </Element>
        <Element name="uk">
          <br />
          <h1 className="display-4">London</h1>
          <Table info={info.uk} />
        </Element>
        <Element name="ny">
          <br />
          <h1 className="display-4">New York</h1>
          <Table info={info.ny} />
        </Element>
      </Container>
    );
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <SearchContainer />
      {spinner === true || spinner === null ? (
        <Standby />
      ) : (
        <React.Fragment>{tables}</React.Fragment>
      )}
    </div>
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to refactor your async function code inside the hook according to the documentation, here: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14326
2. Consider adding Hook dependencies as you see fit: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#conditionally-firing-an-effect

Answer (score 0):

As described from the above post, I'm trying to visualize your solution

```
useEffect(() => {
  let isCancelled = false;
  setSpinner(true);

  async function test() {
     tor = await axios.get('http://localhost:8080/api/tor');
     uk = await axios.get('http://localhost:8080/api/uk');
     ny = await axios.get('http://localhost:8080/api/ny');
    
     setInfo({
      tor: tor.data,
      uk: uk.data,
      ny: ny.data,
    });
     
  }

  if (!isCancelled) {
    test();
    setSpinner(false);
  }

  return () => {
    isCancelled = true;
  };
}, []);
```